# Span with lines jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to create span with lines like in notebook. When text is added to span i want the lines to be there.

I am appending text like

`$('spanid').text('texthere')`

I tried using underline on css but the problem is the span is not taking the whole parent width.

also tried using `border-bottom` but not getting what i desire.

Desired Output : I am appending text on a span. Sometimes not text. What i want is when no text span should have lines. To be exact 10 lines. When i add lines the text should have lines under it. And depending on the text lines, lines should be appended to the span so that there will always be 10 lines.

FYI: **span with multiple lines with underlines**

searching using above but maybe i am looking at it the wrong way.

Any suggestion is appreaciated. (pls not plugin only jquery)

```js
var data = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. ";

$("#printmemo").html(data);//set data using html() need to add more lines after inserting data no idea how to add lines
```

```css
.memo{
    font-size: 20px;
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;*/
    /*text-align: center;*/
    text-decoration: underline;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block; 
}
.memo:empty{
    display:inline-block; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span type="text" id="printmemo" class="memo"></span>
```

Comment: Could you please share your efforts?

Comment: Maybe a small, repeating background image for the span's container could be a solution for this problem.

Comment: @GolezTrol how do i go with it?i mean how would i tell that i am on tenth line or not yet?can you show it in my snippet. Updated a snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use `repeating-linear-gradient` for the lines. In this case you also need to watch for `line-height` and gradient size. In example `.lines` has line height equals to `21px` (14 * 1.5) so gradient size must be `21px` too: 20px for transparent space and 1px for the line. You could change color of lines to any without problem

```css
.lines {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0, transparent 20px, #bbb 20px, #bbb 21px);
    background-attachment: local;
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 230px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span class="lines">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum dignissimos id ipsa iste nisi porro ratione tenetur vero. Delectus dolores earum expedita, harum hic nisi tenetur? Eveniet fuga sunt tempora.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum dignissimos id ipsa iste nisi porro ratione tenetur vero. Delectus dolores earum expedita, harum hic nisi tenetur? Eveniet fuga sunt tempora.
</span>
```

Comment: i really find this very nice by the way i can change span to div but i really need to make it work for span. when i use span it is not working why is that?

Comment: @BrownmanRevival you want use `<span>` instead of  `<div>`? Just add `display:block;` to your element, and it should be fine. I've updated the answer.

Comment: i have 1 issue when i print it the underline is not showing?any idea why.when i use image it is showing

Comment: @BrownmanRevival you should check 'Background' checkbox in your printing settings. In Chrome its `+ More seetings` - > `Backgournd graphics` in left sidebar. Screenshot - http://c2n.me/3xqZ1XG

Comment: what could be causing the missing lines?im missing 2nd sometimes 3rd sometimes 3rd and 4th

Comment: @BrownmanRevival hmm, hard to say, could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: this is not the exact same problem but you can see here that only 3 lines are showing but in before the print preview at 4 are present what could be the problem *(ex :if you have empty text or has one line text only 3 lines are showing)* [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5xxb1obu/)

Answer (score 2):

A **background image** underline as suggested.

```
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
</div>
```

**Style**

```
div {
    height: 160px;
    width:100%;
    line-height: 16px;
    background: url("http://underscorejs.org/favicon.ico") repeat;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W7w9s/97/)

> Note: The **line-height** & the image height needs to be same.

For **10** lines -

`line-height` is `16px`, so the `div` `height` should be `160px`.

Comment: looks great..i need only 10 lines how to tell that only 10 lines.. in fiddle it is more than 10

Comment: Needs some calculations for this.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try to play with `<hr>` with a JS function which inserts it every X words and adjust your `<hr>` with a simple CSS to align it just under your text.

```
<hr class='line'>

.line{
    position: relative;
    top: -5px; /* Something like that */
}
```

Hope it helps